# Number Variable from UserForm not passing to Module

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a UserForm, and in the third box, I need to select a Brazilian state. I have constructed a list and attempted to use a Case statement to link the state name to a corresponding number. The problem I'm encountering is that the number doesn't pass to my module; it returns "0" or "".

[image]

**UserForm1**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Box_Estados.AddItem "Acre"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Alagoas"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Amapá"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Amazonas"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Bahia"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Ceará"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Distrito Federal"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Espírito Santo"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Goiás"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Maranhão"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Mato Grosso"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Mato Grosso do Sul"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Minas Gerais"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Pará"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Paraíba"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Paraná"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Pernambuco"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Piauí"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Rio de Janeiro"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Rio Grande do Norte"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Rio Grande do Sul"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Rondônia"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Roraima"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Santa Catarina"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "São Paulo"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Sergipe"
    Box_Estados.AddItem "Tocantins"
    
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Prosseguir_Click()

    Dim tempEstado As Integer
    Select Case Box_Estados.Value
        Case "Acre"
            tempEstado = 1
        Case "Alagoas"
            tempEstado = 2
        Case "Amapá"
            tempEstado = 4
        Case "Amazonas"
            tempEstado = 3
        Case "Bahia"
            tempEstado = 5
        Case "Ceará"
            tempEstado = 6
        Case "Distrito Federal"
            tempEstado = 7
        Case "Espírito Santo"
            tempEstado = 8
        Case "Goiás"
            tempEstado = 9
        Case "Maranhão"
            tempEstado = 10
        Case "Mato Grosso"
            tempEstado = 13
        Case "Mato Grosso do Sul"
            tempEstado = 12
        Case "Minas Gerais"
            tempEstado = 11
        Case "Pará"
            tempEstado = 14
        Case "Paraíba"
            tempEstado = 15
        Case "Paraná"
            tempEstado = 18
        Case "Pernambuco"
            tempEstado = 16
        Case "Piauí"
            tempEstado = 17
        Case "Rio de Janeiro"
            tempEstado = 19
        Case "Rio Grande do Norte"
            tempEstado = 20
        Case "Rio Grande do Sul"
            tempEstado = 23
        Case "Rondônia"
            tempEstado = 21
        Case "Roraima"
            tempEstado = 22
        Case "Santa Catarina"
            tempEstado = 24
        Case "São Paulo"
            tempEstado = 26
        Case "Sergipe"
            tempEstado = 25
        Case "Tocantins"
            tempEstado = 27
    End Select

    tempUser = TextBox_Login.Text
    tempPass = TextBox_Senha.Text
    tempDtFinal = dtFinalBox.Text
    
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

**Module1**

```
Public tempUser As String
Public tempPass As String
Public tempDtFinal As String
Public tempEstado As Integer

UserForm1.Show vbModeless

Do While UserForm1.Visible
    DoEvents
Loop

Login = tempUser
Senha = tempPass
DataFinal = tempDtFinal
Estado = tempEstado
```

Here's a screenshot from my Debug Console.

[image]

What can I do to solve this? Here's an example of what I need to happen.

Example 1:
User selected Tocantins; Tocantins corresponds to 27. Therefore, let's assume that the variable tempEstado would be equal to 27.

Example 2:
User selected Rondônia; Rondônia corresponds to 21. Therefore, let's assume that the variable tempEstado would be equal to 21.

Comment: You have tempEstado declared twice:  in the Module and in the Click event.  Try removing the declaration from the Click event.

Comment: _Microsoft documentation:_

> [Understanding scope and visibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Answer (score 0):

You have a global and a local variable with the same name. With the `Case` method you declare the local variable. The simplest way to correct this issue is that after defining the local variable's value then set the global to this value.

```
        '.
        '.
        '.  
        Case "Tocantins"
            tempEstado = 27
    End Select

    tempUser = TextBox_Login.Text
    tempPass = TextBox_Senha.Text
    tempDtFinal = dtFinalBox.Text
    
    Module1.tempEstado = tempEstado

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives a good explanation:  [Property Procedures - Passing Information to and from Forms](https://peltiertech.com/Excel/PropertyProcedures.html)

I create a form with three textboxes, one combobox and a command button:
[image]

Controls are named:  `txtUser`, `txtPassword`, `txtDate`, `ComboBox1` and `CommandButton1`.

I pass the combo-box values to the form as a 2D array.
The combo-box is set to have a *ColumnCount* of 2 and *ColumnWidths* of 0 pt;28.35 pt.  The combo-box will hold both the state number and name, but the number will be hidden by the 0 width column.

- (0,0) = 1, (0,1) = "Acre"
- (1,0) = 2, (1,1) = "Alagoas"
- etc

`AfterUpdate` events capture the textbox values and `Change` event to capture the combobox values.  These values are stored in module level variables.

`Property` procedures are used to pass the module level variable values out to the calling procedure.

The code behind the form is:

```
Option Explicit

Private mSelectedState As Long
Private mUser As String
Private mPWD As String
Private mDate As Date

'Populate the combobox with state values.
Public Sub AddStates(ListItems As Variant)
    ComboBox1.List = ListItems
End Sub

'Hide the form when OK is pressed and pass code execution back to the main calling procedure.
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub


'Capture the textbox values into the module level variables.
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    mSelectedState = CLng(ComboBox1.Value)
End Sub
Private Sub txtDate_AfterUpdate()
    mDate = CDate(txtDate.Value)
End Sub
Private Sub txtPassword_Change()
    mPWD = txtPassword.Value
End Sub
Private Sub txtUser_AfterUpdate()
    mUser = txtUser.Value
End Sub

'Pass the module level variables out of the form.
Public Property Get StateValue() As Long
    StateValue = mSelectedState
End Property
Public Property Get Password() As String
    Password = mDate
End Property
Public Property Get User() As String
    User = mUser
End Property
Public Property Get DateValue() As Date
    DateValue = mDate
End Property

'Tried to close the form using the 'X', cancel that and press the OK button instead.
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        CommandButton1_Click
    End If
End Sub
```

The code in module 1 is:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    
    'Create a 2D array from a 1D array of states
    Dim StateList As Variant
    StateList = Array(1, "Acre", 2, "Alagoas", 3, "Amapa", 4, "Amazonas", 5, "Bahia")

    Dim ListArray() As Variant
    ReDim ListArray((UBound(StateList) - 1) / 2, 1)

    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    For x = 0 To UBound(ListArray)
        ListArray(x, 0) = StateList(y)
        ListArray(x, 1) = StateList(y + 1)
        y = y + 2
    Next x
    
    'NOTE:  If you want you can replace the above with a sheet range reference that contains your states:
    'Dim ListArray As Variant
    'ListArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B6").Value
    
    'Create an instance of the form.
    Dim MyForm As UserForm1
    Set MyForm = New UserForm1
    
    With MyForm
        .Caption = "Logon Form"
        .AddStates ListArray 'Pass the state list to the form.
        .Show 'Show the form.  Not modeless otherwise this code will continue to run and the form will vanish.
        
        'This code will run when the form is hidden by pressing the OK button.
        Debug.Print "Login is: " & .User
        Debug.Print "Password is: " & .Password
        Debug.Print "Final Date is: " & .DateValue
        Debug.Print "State Number is: " & .StateValue
        
    End With
    
    Unload MyForm

End Sub
```